# Not getting response for same query if executed more than 10 times in same script using node-mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

Few hours back I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36258653/is-it-required-to-clear-buffer-in-node-js-if-yes-how-if-no-what-is-the-issue). I was troubleshooting it when I Zeroed in on this current issue.

Here is the loop, if I execute the function `selectPhotoById` more than 10 times, I get response for only 10 queries.

Example, for the following loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    db.selectPhotoById("12246", function (res) {
        console.log(res[0].ID);
    });
}
```

in the console response, I get

```
12246
12246
12246
12246
```

This works fine, but if i increase the loop like

```
for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
    db.selectPhotoById("12246", function (res) {
        console.log(res[0].ID);
    });
}
```

I get only 10 IDs as response

```
12246
12246
12246
12246
12246
12246
12246
12246
12246
12246
```

Here is the code of the file where the queries are written

```
var mysql = require('node-mysql');
var DB = mysql.DB;
var photo = new DB({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'photo'
});

function DataBase() { 
}

DataBase.prototype.selectPhotoById = function (photo_id, callback) {
    photo.connect(function (conn, cb) {
        conn.query("select * from photo where ID =" + photo_id, function (err, res) {
            if (err)
                throw err;

            return callback(res);
        });
    });
}

DataBase.prototype.insertThumb = function(photo_id, blob, size, callback){
    photo.connect(function(conn, cb){
       var query = 'INSERT INTO photo.photo_thumb (`photo_id`, `thumb`, `size`) values ("'+photo_id+'", "'+blob+'", "'+size+'")';
       conn.query(query, function (err, res){
            if (err) throw err;
            return callback(res);
       }); 
    });
}

DataBase.prototype.checkThumb = function(photo_id, size, callback){
    photo.connect(function(conn, cb){
        var query = 'SELECT count(*) as count FROM photo.photo_thumb WHERE photo_id = "'+photo_id+'" AND size = "'+size+'"'
        conn.query(query, function(err, res){
            if(err)throw err;
            return callback(res);
        });
    });
}

module.exports = DataBase;
```

The same issue is happening for the insert query as well.
Is this an issue with the [node-mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mysql) package or the issue is with my code?

Comment: try to handle `err` into console log as well (directly in prototype body).

Comment: ok let me try it out.

Comment: @mitkosoft Same response even if i do `console.log(err)` in query.

Comment: so there is no error at all, just stops after 10 repeats?

Comment: Yes, exactly. No error at all. I am really confused. Right now I am trying out another [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) and see if it works there.

Comment: I would try it with `mysql` or `mysql2` instead of `node-mysql` to avoid unnecessary layers.

Comment: Yes @mscdex I figured that out, I just used `mysql` package and it worked just fine. I was in the impression that `node-mysql` was the better package unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the issue probably was with the `node-mysql` package as I found out after using another [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) package for Node.js which also seems to be more popular than the one I was using, and more stable. Everything's working fine with the new package. I'll probably put up this issue with the Author of node-mysql on github for resolution.